# why xlwings suppresses logging to a file

Tags: python, logging, xlwings

In my `app.py` module I set up a logger with console and file handlers like this:

```
import logging


logger = logging.getLogger('app')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('gsam_log.txt')
console_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
c_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)-12s: %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
f_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')

console_handler.setFormatter(c_formatter)
file_handler.setFormatter(f_formatter)
logger.addHandler(console_handler)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

If I work in Python Console and I do: `from app import logger` it works as expected - printing both to console and the file. I would like to use this logger to log from my `xlwings` subs (decorated with `@xw.sub`). But for some reason the logs are only sent to console and not to the file. Below is the code from `test.py` module, which I import as UDF module via xlwings.

```
from app import logger
import xlwings as xw


@xw.sub
def test():
    logger.debug('test')
    logger.info('test')
    logger.warning('test')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not too familiar with how `xlwings` works but due to the intricacies of how the `logging` module works, I would recommend not creating loggers in the global scope of your modules, but instead lazy-create them as needed.

In many cases, logs created in the global scope are created *before* any code is run. Then, some other code re-configures logging which causes per-existing logs to be removed and their configuration to be forgotten. This is why the `disable_existing_loggers=False` argument exists for `logging.config` functions (e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.fileConfig).

To see if this is the case, I would recommend moving your log definition code to a function, and calling it as needed, for example:

import logging

```
# app.py
_logger = None

def get_logger():
    global _logger
    if _logger is None:

        _logger = logging.getLogger('app')
        _logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        # ... continue to define your logger ...

    return _logger
```

Then in your function:

```
from app import get_logger
import xlwings as xw

@xw.sub
def test():
    logger = get_logger()
    logger.debug('test')
    logger.info('test')
    logger.warning('test')
```

It should be noted that this is not the "cleanest" way to use logging (usually this should not be required) but if the problem is really some other module messing with the logging configuration, it might be difficult to work around.

Comment: Interesting. I won’t be able to test before Monday, but I get the feeling it will work :)

Comment: In the `get_logger` function did you mean `if _logger is None:` instead of `is not` or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes I did, sorry about that. I updated my answer in accordance.